# Understanding const inside a template

Tags: c++, templates, constants

If you write a template like this one

```
template <typename T>
using X = const T;
```

what's the meaning of const T?

To know about it I wrote this program:

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha
    << std::is_same_v<X<int&>, int&> << '\n'
    << std::is_same_v<X<const int*>, const int* const> << '\n'
    << std::is_same_v<X<const int&>, const int&> << '\n';
```

and for my surprise all the answers were true.

Why X < int&> is an int& and not a 'const int&'?

I compiled it with gcc 7.3.0 and clang++ 6.0. Same answer.

Comment: This is simply how stuff works. If `T` is "pointer to int" (`int *`), then it's reasonable for `const T` to be "const pointer to int" (`int *const`), rather than "pointer to const int" (`const int *`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reference to const int is one thing.  A const reference to an int is nonsense.

Under the rules of C++, when you const qualify a reference, nothing happens.

This makes lots of sense if you are used to east const, and little if you are a west const user.

```
int const&
```

is a reference to a const int.

```
int&const
```

is the same as

```
int&
```

Comment: *"east const"* *"west const"* Hah!

Comment: @holyblack east const best const west const worst const. (Say that 5 times fast)

Answer (score 1):

> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a [*typedef-name*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.typedef#nt:typedef-name) ([[dcl.typedef]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.typedef), [[temp.param]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple)) or [*decltype-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#nt:decltype-specifier) ([[dcl.type.simple]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple)), in which case the cv-qualifiers are ignored. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> typedef int& A;
> const A aref = 3;   // ill-formed; lvalue reference to non-const initialized with rvalue
> ```
>
> The type of `aref` is “lvalue reference to `int`”, not “lvalue reference to `const int`”. — *end example* ]

[[dcl.ref]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#1)